# Good Practice to set a constant variable

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a simple code in NodeJS app that sends a request with the following hypothetic url

```js
    private getApiUrl(): string {
        return `https://${domainExample}.host-example.com/API/version/example/${exampleValue}`;
    }
```

Is it a better practice to make a separate file called something like `Constant.ts` and have this url a constant? or Is it still acceptable to have this url in string literal.

Constant.ts

```js
export const BASE_URL = 'https://%s.qualtrics.com/API/v3/imported-data-projects/%s'
// assume these files are separate

private getApiUrl(): string {
  return util.format(BASE_URL, domainExample, exampleValue) ;
}
```

Comment: Are you going to change it? Do you want to change it from command line/environment? If not, use template literal, if yes use dotenv

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal recommendation here as it really depends upon a number of factors.

First off, it's desirable to avoid repeating the same string definition for a resource like this in multiple places.  So, if putting it in a `const` separate file allows you to share definitions across multiple modules, then that would generally be desirable.  But, sometime collecting all strings into a separate file complicate the encaspulation, modularity and ease of encapsulated maintenance.  So, that's all a tradeoff.  One could really only offer an opinion on how to do that level of tradeoff by understanding the overall layout of the code across many modules and understanding which modules may be reused in other contexts.

If this URL structure would rarely (if ever) change and isn't used elsewhere, then the embedded template string is just simpler to code and read.  No need to add more lines of code with the separate `const` declaration and `util.format()` call.  The template string is the simplest structure and it only adds complexity to move it out to `constants.ts`.

If this URL structure may need to occasionally be edited along with other related URLs, then there may be significant maintenance benefit to collecting all the URLs that may need such maintenance into one module such as `constants.ts`.  If the domain or API version needed to be modified, then there would be a significant benefit to having all the URLs that you use with the API in one place such as `constants.ts`.

Since these two structures above are in conflict, you have to decide which tradeoff benefits the needs of your project better.  I try to make my code as simple as possible to meet the needs which leads me to the embedded template string unless there's a clear need to separate out all the URL strings (for maintenance reasons).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a few more cases to @jfriend00's answer when it might be helpful to store such URLs into a separate constant:

- If it is not obvious to the reader what this URL structure points to or the usage of it it may be better to store it in a constant with a self describing name (like `const QUALTRICS_API_URL = "..."`) in order to avoid so called ["magic strings"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string).
- If this URL structure is used in several places in the code it may be better to store it in a constant to avoid potential differences between them in the future.